# Oracle trigger for updating denormalised table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have these tables:

**Employee**(EmployeeID, NameSurname, PhoneNumber, Email)

**Contract**(ContractID, Date, *EmployeeID*, NameSurname)

I want to create trigger on UPDATE for Contract table: when I update "EmployeeID" in Contract table, NameSurname should be updated accordingly, from Employee table. Also, I have trigger "TBU_Contract_Prohib" which doesn't allow direct change of NameSurname field in Contract. I wrote this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TBU_Contract"
 BEFORE UPDATE OF "EmployeeID" ON "Contract"
 FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
v_namesurname VARCHAR(50);
pragma autonomous_transaction;
  BEGIN
   EXECUTE immediate 'alter trigger "TBU_Contract_Prohib" disable';
   COMMIT;

   SELECT "NameSurname"
   INTO v_namesurname
   FROM "Employee"
   WHERE "EmployeeID" = :NEW."EmployeeID";

   UPDATE "Contract"
   SET "NameSurname"        = v_namesurname
   WHERE "EmployeeID" = :NEW."EmployeeID";

   EXECUTE immediate 'alter trigger " TBU_Contract_Prohib" enable';
   COMMIT;
  END;
```

This compiles without errors. However, when I test it, for example:

```
UPDATE "Contract"
SET
"EmployeeID" = 2
WHERE
"ContractID" = 2;
```

i get error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TBU_Contract", line 14
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TBU_Contract'
00060. 00000 -  "deadlock detected while waiting for resource"
*Cause:    Transactions deadlocked one another while waiting for resources.
*Action:   Look at the trace file to see the transactions and resources
           involved. Retry if necessary.
```

What is wrong and how is it possible to make this work?

Comment: This doesn't make sense on a whole lot of different levels.  Is this a real problem?  If so, your approach is fundamentally problematic.  Or is this some sort of sick homework assignment?

Comment: This is the mutating error...you can't update a table which is firing a trigger..

Comment: @Trijit: while you are correct that the trigger might produce an ORA-04091 if it got that far, that's not what's happening here. The error in question is a deadlock because the first ALTER TRIGGER blocked because there was an update in progress against the table.

Comment: @JustinCave its homework assignment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following would work better for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TBU_Contract"
  BEFORE UPDATE OF "EmployeeID" ON "Contract"
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SELECT "NameSurname"
    INTO :NEW."NameSurname"
    FROM "Employee"
    WHERE "EmployeeID" = :NEW."EmployeeID";
END;
```

Best of luck.